# Does the more massive body always orbit the barycenter at orbital velocity?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, astrophysics, astronomy

As far as I know, there's no rule that planets should orbit stars, just that a planet which **happens to be** moving with orbital speed relative to a star will end up orbiting it. My question is if the same thing is true for the orbit of a star around the barycenter of the system. Intuitively it would be the same, meaning that stars would not always orbit the barycenter. But what would happen if a star doesn't move with orbital speed? It would probably *fall* to the barycenter. And that will make a new barycenter. It sounds weird. what's the truth?

Comment: FWIW, the Sun's speed relative to the Solar System barycentre is quite small, with a mean ~12.67 m/s https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0ZXB.png See https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/28036/16685

Comment: In addition to BowlOfRed's answer one should add that orbits in a many-body problem are often chaotic and unstable, and planets and even stars are often being ejected from their systems. When that happens the "old barycenter" becomes a somewhat useless concept because it will move "out" of the remaining system and the remaining bodies do not seem to orbit around it in any approximation.

Answer (score 4):

The barycenter is just a fancy name for "center of mass".

For a binary system, the only way for an object to reach the center of mass is to collide with the other object.

For a more complex system, it could reach the center of mass without colliding.  But in neither case does this "make a new barycenter".  In the absence of external forces, the center of mass will not accelerate.  Even if an object reaches that point or if there are collisions.

> Why is the planet not "required" to orbit the barycenter (it only does so if it "happens" to move with the right velocity), but the star is required?

When 2 objects orbit, they always move around their center of mass.  So both objects orbit the barycenter.   The barycenter will always be on a line between the two objects, with a ratio of distances that is inverse to the ratio of the object's masses.

So there is no "right" velocity.  All (non-intersecting) 2 body orbits will have both objects moving around the barycenter.  It's not possible for both objects to be on one side of their center of mass, so if one is spinning around it, the other must always be as well.

Comment: Thanks. But my question mainly was a yes or no question, does the more massive body always orbit the barycenter or not? If yes, why?

Comment: In a 2 body system, sure.  (though whether anything "orbits the barycenter" is sort of a philosophical question, not a physical one). 

In a multi-body system, it certainly doesn't have nice circles around the barycenter.  https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/14684/what-does-the-suns-orbit-within-the-solar-system-look-like

Comment: Thanks. Now comes the "why" part of my question. Why is the planet not "required" to orbit the barycenter (it only does so if it "happens" to move with the right velocity), but the star is required? (I'm talking about a two body system.)

Comment: You call it philosophical because of the theory of relativity? OK, let's talk about it like we talk about the earth orbiting the sun.

Comment: No, I call it philosophical because the barycenter isn't physical.  The objects are moving in response to the other objects.  The barycenter is just a mathematical description.  
 
In a 2 body system, both objects will orbit around the barycenter because the barycenter is necessarily on a straight line between the two.   There is no "right" velocity.  All non-intersecting orbits would have that property.

Comment: So what [NASA](https://spaceplace.nasa.gov/barycenter/en/) says about barycenter is just kind of kidding?

Comment: By 'right velocity' I mean orbital velocity.

Comment: I understand from your answer that the statement "Earth and the moon orbit their shared barycenter" is just _technically_ true, but doesn't say anything helpful about orbits, as it's not _more_ true than saying that "the moon orbits Earth". Did I understand you properly?

Comment: Pretty much.  From the inertial frame where the barycenter is at rest, both objects in a 2-body system will move in ellipses.  Each ellipse will be a reflection, with size scaling in inverse proportion to their masses.   So yes, each orbit will have the barycenter within.

Comment: So such a statement like NASA's statement cited above: "We say that planets orbit stars, but that’s not the whole truth. Planets and stars actually orbit around their common center of mass" - is meaningless, since both are equal whole truth?